# sorting logfiles based on their content

Tags: bash, sorting

I want to sort filenames (log files) based on some common content that exists in all files.  Each log file starts with a ‘p’ followed by some numbers and ends with ‘.log. such as:

```
P029387.log
```

In each logfile, there is a common string: “count of operations is ”  such as:

```
total access time is 321 seconds
```

I’d like to write a bash command that will output the above string found in each file, plus the filename itself, such as:

```
"total access time is 267 seconds"  P110234.log
"total access time is 47 seconds"   P202931.log
"total access time is 55 seconds"   P239871.log
```

So far, I’ve been able to sort the content of the logfiles but not to print their filenames:

```
find . -name p*.log -exec grep "count of operations is “ {} \; |sort -n –k5
```

but the output is limited to:

```
"total access time is 267 seconds"
"total access time is 47 seconds"
"total access time is 55 seconds"
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about that exact format then just:

```
grep 'total access time is ' P*.log
```

possibly with `-H` if that isn't the default (or disabled in default arguments/alias) will get you:

```
P110234.log:"total access time is 267 seconds"
P202931.log:"total access time is 47 seconds"
P239871.log:"total access time is 55 seconds"
```

If you do want your exact output then it might be easiest to use something like:

```
awk '/total access time is /{print $0,FILENAME}' P*.log
```

or for even column spacing:

```
awk '/total access time is /{print $0"\t"FILENAME}' P*.log | column -t
```

Answer (score 1):

Use option `grep -H` which prints the filename :

```
find . -name p*.log -exec grep -H "count of operations is “ {} \; |sort -n –k5
```